# How to display names in a CMS collection as a single paragraph, comma seperated

Tags: html, css, content-management-system

I have a list of clients I want to display in a single paragraph, see the image. I'm not sure how to set this up in HTML + CSS.

[example iamge[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vynd7.png)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example, mind that using `innerHTML` is not always good.

```js
const el = document.getElementById('list')
const list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
el.innerHTML = list.join(', ')
```

```css
.header {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<p class='header'>Clients</p>
<p id='list' />
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how it can be implemented:

```css
.frame {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 70%;
}

.frame > h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="frame">
  <h1>Clients</h1>
  <p>
    One, Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten, Eleven, Twelve, Thirteen, Fourteen, Fifteen, Sixteen, Seventeen, Eighteen, Nineteen, Twenty
  </p>
</div>
```